# Как я могу получить заголовки ответа responseHeaders() из PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineLoadingInfo()

Tags: pyqt6, qwebengineview, qtwebengine

Вот пример кода:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineLoadingInfo
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebEngineView()
    view.load(QUrl('https://duckduckgo.com'))
    page = view.page()
    info = QWebEngineLoadingInfo().responseHeaders()
    response_headers = page.loadingChanged(info)
    print(response_headers)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Как получить http-заголовки ответов после каждой загрузки? Я пытался сделать это:

```
page = view.page()
info = QWebEngineLoadingInfo().responseHeaders()
response_headers = page.loadingChanged(info)
print(response_headers)
```

Но я получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: QWebEngineLoadingInfo(other: QWebEngineLoadingInfo): not enough arguments
```